# how to recognize such hidden symbol in word

Tags: microsoft-word

In my word file, there seems a special hidden symbol at the beginning of the second page:

[image]

If I put cursor before '#2' and press Backspace key, it doesn't move.
Only if I put cursor at the end of the first page and press Delete key could I merge 2 pages into 1.

I tried to search for the speical character, but it's not ^p (new paragraph) or ^l (hard line) or ^m (new page).

What is it and how could I search for it?

Comment: Post the file if you wish it examined.

Comment: how could i upload a file?

Comment: Any file-sharing service - OneDrive, Dropbox etc. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: If you ensure that the special character is surrounded by text that is easy to find (e.g. "yyy" and "zzz", save the file as a single-file "Word XML Document" (you get a .xml file) or perhaps even the slightly simpler Word 2003 XML document (also .xml), then open that in a plain text editor such as notepad, you *might* be able to see the XML that Word has inserted. That could help. Normally the yyy and zzz would be in a "run element" inside a "text element" inside a "paragraph element, e.g. like this `<w:p><w:t><w:r>yyy</w:r></w:t><w:p>` so anything between the yyy and zzz could be interesting.

Comment: @yokki thank you very much. the mysterious dot is pageBreakBefore. after i removed the style the paragraphs now do not have a page break before it.

Comment: Thanks for posting back with the finding. Suggest you post your own answer detailing what you did and what you found, then mark it as as The Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the symbol is caused by the "page break before" paragraph setting.
To remove it, select the paragraph, right click and choose "Paragraph...", go to "Line and Page Breaks", uncheck the "Page break before" item.